# KMeans / ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples:

Tags: python, algorithm, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, stability

My initial data is :

`data_init = pd.read_csv('data_merged.csv')`

Total periode to cover 25 months

```
initial_period_data = data_init[(data_init['order_purchase_timestamp'] >= earliest_timestamp) & (data_init['order_purchase_timestamp'] < initial_period_end)]

process_data(initial_period_data) #it is a function to recalculate all the features on this date
```

*I select then numerical variables and apply scaler to normalise :*

```
initial_period_data_num = initial_period_data.select_dtypes(include="number").fillna(0)
scaler_init = StandardScaler()
initial_period_data_num_scaled = scaler_init.fit_transform(initial_period_data_num)
```

*Then, I train Kmeans*

```
model_init = KMeans(n_clusters=6)
model_init = model_init.fit(initial_period_data_num_scaled)
model_init_labels = model_init.labels_
initial_period_data['labels'] = model_init_labels


from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

initial_period_end = initial_period_data['order_purchase_timestamp'].max()
period_end = data_init['order_purchase_timestamp'].max()
```

**
I block from there**
*I want to iterate over the whole period starting from the initial period of 12 months on period intervals of 2 weeks until the end of the period to be covered and then compare the initial clusters and new clusters*

```
# Liste pour stocker les scores ARI
ari_scores = []

total_periods = 25

for p in range(2, total_periods + 1, 2):
    current_period_end = initial_period_end + pd.DateOffset(weeks=p)
    data_period = data_init[(data_init['order_purchase_timestamp'] >= initial_period_end) & (data_init['order_purchase_timestamp'] < current_period_end)]
    
    data_period_group = process_data(data_period)

    # Sélection colonnes numériques
    data_period_num = data_period_group.select_dtypes(include="number").fillna(0)

    # Scaler init
    
    data_period_scaled = scaler_init.fit_transform(data_period_num)

    # KMeans init
    model_init.predict(data_period_scaled)
    p_labels = model_init.labels_



    # Calculer le score ARI pour la période actuelle
    ari_p = adjusted_rand_score(model_init_labels, p_labels)
    ari_scores.append([p, ari_p])
```

But I have this error
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [28876, 2050]
Can you please tell me where I am wrong

Hello everybody, I need your help
In order to establish a maintenance contract for the customer segmentation algorithm, I must test its stability over time and see, for example, when customers change clusters.For that, I have to recalculate all the features according to a given period.
I want to iterate over the whole period starting from the initial period of 12 months on period intervals of 2 weeks until the end of the period to be covered and then compare the initial clusters and new clusters. But I have this error
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [28876, 2050]
Can you please tell me where I am wrong